# How to create the tabs with center aligned using CommunityToolkit in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

Am new to xamarin forms, how to create Tabview, TabViewItems should be aligned in center, using communityToolkit in xamarin forms, want to create the view as below
Below is the code :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:UIControls.Tabs"
             xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
             x:Class="UIControls.Tabs.BottomTabs">
    <converter:CustomTabView IsSwipeEnabled="True" 
                             TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
                             SelectedIndex="0" 
                             Style="{StaticResource TabViewStyle}"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <converter:CustomTabViewItem Text="Configuration"
                        Style="{StaticResource TabsItemStyle}"
                         IsSelected="True"
                                     Icon="ic_router.png">
            <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="TAB 1" />
                </StackLayout>
            </xct:TabViewItem.Content>

        </converter:CustomTabViewItem>
        <converter:CustomTabViewItem
            Text="Monitoring"
                     Style="{StaticResource TabsItemStyle}"
                             Icon="ic_router.png">
            <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                <ContentView />
            </xct:TabViewItem.Content>

        </converter:CustomTabViewItem>
        <converter:CustomTabViewItem 
            Icon="ic_router.png"
            Text="Diagnostics"
                          Style="{StaticResource TabsItemStyle}">
            <xct:TabViewItem.Content>
                <ContentView />
            </xct:TabViewItem.Content>

        </converter:CustomTabViewItem>
    </converter:CustomTabView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Required as below
[image]

Comment: please show us your code/xaml

Comment: Added code and screenshot, please help

Comment: try setting HorizontalOptions to Center

Comment: Not working, when i set HorizontalOptions to Center, selection area gets reduced

Comment: What is `converter:CustomTabView`? I don't recognize that. Why does the XAML you show not have "Configuration", "Monitoring", "Diagnostics" in it? How does "Tab 1" relate to those 3 tabs at the bottom? Impossible to tell what is happening here.

Comment: Could you show the code with `TabsItemStyle` ?